# Duplicate or clone instance of component Angular

Tags: angular

I'm writing an Angular 4 application where I'm required to display the same instance of a component in two places of my template and want to know if this is even a possibility in Angular.

Let's say I have parent component whose template looks like the following:

```
<div>
    <childcomponent></childcomponent>
    <childcomponent></childcomponent>
</div>
```

I know this would normally create two individual instances of childcomponent but is there a way to make them share the same instance?  I have tried using ComponentFactoryResolver to generate the component programmatically and then using ViewContainerRef to inject the same instance into the template as shown below but only the first one gets added and no errors are generated.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div>
    <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
    <ng-container #vc2></ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: out of curiousity, why would you like to do something like that?

Comment: In your case, I'll make a child-component that use @ Input and @ OutPut to maintain a synchronization. That's, different component but same data

Comment: @dee zg  Let's say I have a navigator component that keeps track of active links and expanded dropdowns.  Instead of having to create a service that keeps track of all that if I could just have a singleton of that component and not worry about creating a service.  I could place the navigator as many different places as I want and the state would be the same.

Comment: @jurgenw yes, i see your point. as @Eliseo pointed out, and as you say 'the state would be the same' - its actually the state you want to be the same (which different components will reflect) and not the components themselves. I am not aware of the way to accomplish what you ask because, by definition, its different instances. If i were you, i would go in direction of implementing state management that all components of interest share. For example, your state could be `Observable` which emits changes and each of your components listen to it and behave accordingly. `redux` / `ngrx` state style